# What is the name of the phenomenon of the subsequent semantic convergence of a borrowed cognate?

Tags: terminology, etymology, historical-linguistics

What is the name of the phenomenon of the subsequent semantic convergence of a borrowed cognate?
For example, similar occurs in for the borrowed Latin 'video', which, however, of course, is original p.i.e. cognate of Russian (Slavic) 'вид' ('vid') and all its derivatives; and its semantic associative convergence takes place.

- about associative convergence. it is also automatically mass perceived as the single-root words.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Which semantic convergence? You mention Slavic languages borrowing _video_ from Latin (in what sense?) and then mention the inherited cognate (which means what?), but you don’t say anything about what semantic convergence takes place. As it stands, it’s pretty much impossible to figure out what phenomenon exactly it is you’re talking about…

Comment: Janus Bahs Jacquet, about associative convergence. it is also automatically perceived as the single-root words. In general, I have already received the answer, and if you cannot understand something - you are able to look at the answer by T1nts.

Comment: Okay, but doublets do not have any relation to semantic or associative convergence as mentioned in your question. For example, the verb _find_ is a doublet of the words _fouse_ (ready, eager, willing), _pontic_ (an artificial tooth) and _path_, but there is absolutely no semantic or associative connection or convergence between any of those, and certainly no English speaker would ever consider them a single root in English, not even an etymologist.

Comment: Janus Bahs Jacquet, i don't know anything about the interrelationship of "fouse" and "find" now, but the relationship between "fire" and "pyro" may be pretty obvious.(And i don't know how the English native speakers perceive this situation, with their analytical and not inflectional language, in which the perception of roots is weakened, probably)

Ok, if such a convergence isn't called as just "etymological doublet" - what is it called?
The phenomenon when the described still occurs.

Comment: The relationship between _fire_ and _pyro_ is not obvious to most English speakers – unless you happen to know your etymologies, they’re just two seemingly unrelated words that mean similar things. Sometimes it’s fairly obvious (_frail_ and _fragile_, for example), other times it’s not. I’m not aware of a term specifically for cognate pairs that are semantically or associatively linked to speakers; if there is one, I don’t know it. But _doublet_ is too broad if the convergence in meaning or association is integral to what you’re looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This phenomenon is called 'doublets', or 'etymological twins'.

Look up more here:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doublet_(linguistics)

Answer (score 1):

Here was a communication gap between @Janus Bahs Jacquet and @Пилум, so to fulfill the gap, you can read those items that close to 'semantic associative convergence':
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paronymic_attraction
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phono-semantic_matching
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(linguistics)

Good luck!